# Total price from different tables

Tags: sql

I have a database with customers, items and orders. This is an exam project, so is maybe not the best for real life. I have this problem. I want a list of what all our customers have bought and a total price of that, but I can't get anything to work.

```
select Kunder.navn,Ordre.*, Indeholder.antal, Varer.*
from Kunder
join Ordre on Kunder.kunde_nr=Ordre.kunde_nr
join Indeholder on Ordre.ordre_nr=Indeholder.ordre_nr
join Varer on Varer.vare_nr=Indeholder.vare_nr
where er_industri=0
order by bestillingsdato
```

I have tried a lot like:

```
sum (Indeholder.antal * Varer.privat_pris) as total
group by Ordre.ordre_nr
```

But I just can't get anything that I've tried, to give me what I'm looking for.

I hope that you want to help me, and that you understand what I mean (I'm not a native english speaker).

I have uploaded an image of our [mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WOrj.jpg), so you can see what our database look like:

[image]

And for clarity, just a translation:

```
Kunder = customers
Varer = items
Ordre = orders
Indeholder = includes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add more columns on your group by clause.
Apart from the aggregate functions [SUM(), COUNT(), AGV()] the same list of columns must be present at the group by clause
and at select clause:

So, generally:

```
  select <col1, col2, col3...>, SUM(...)
  from ...
  group by <col1, col2, col3...>
```

If you want a per customer AND order groupping:

```
  select Kunder.navn, Ordre.ordre_nr, sum (Indeholder.antal * Varer.privat_pris) as total
  from Kunder
  join Ordre on Kunder.kunde_nr=Ordre.kunde_nr
  join Indeholder on Ordre.ordre_nr=Indeholder.ordre_nr
  join Varer on Varer.vare_nr=Indeholder.vare_nr
  where er_industri=0
  group by Kunder.navn, Ordre.ordre_nr
```

You could also do a per customer groupping:

```
   select Kunder.navn, sum (Indeholder.antal * Varer.privat_pris) as total
   from Kunder
   join Ordre on Kunder.kunde_nr=Ordre.kunde_nr
   join Indeholder on Ordre.ordre_nr=Indeholder.ordre_nr
   join Varer on Varer.vare_nr=Indeholder.vare_nr
   where er_industri=0
   group by Kunder.navn
```